How to get a refund for a canceled Swedish rail (SJ) train?
I purchased a ticket for a train from Uppsala to Stockholm online (on the sj.se site). Unfortunately, the train was canceled, and I ended up buying a new ticket for a later train (also on sj.se). While the cost wasn't too high, I would like to get a refund as long as it's a straightforward process. I do see an email and phone number on https://www.sj.se/en/customer-service, but I don't know if that'll really be the right place.
How do I get a refund from SJ, and how difficult is it likely to be?

Hm, did you have to buy anything at all? Last time I had a train cancelled, from Stockholm C, I just went to the help desk (yeah that's still a thing even in Sweden, at least at big stations) and they said I should just board such and such later train. where then the conductor scanned my original ticket and it was fine as he knew my proper train had been cancelled. I would generally expect this or similar to work - it's not your responsibility to do extra work because the train company messed up! Of course, for connecting trains it can be a different story.

I did. In hindsight I should have gone to the help desk, but I ended up just buying a second ticket online

The link to refunds is on this page: https://www.sj.se/om-sj/regler-och-villkor/rattigheter-vid-forsening
(Google translate works fine if needed.)
There are two options. The first is for travel solely with SJ services. The second is for 'resplus', which means that other train operators were involved.
I've used both. It's a simple form to complete and I haven't had a problem getting refunds for delays.
Do check the terms and conditions on that page though. There is a caveat that you can only book a replacement ticket yourself if they haven't offered you an option within 100 minutes. While that caveat doesn't apply to journeys where the train travels less than 150km, what matters is how long the train's journey is, not the distance you travelled, so it depends on your train's departure and destination stations as to whether or not it applies to you (i.e. even though it's less than 150km from Uppsala to Stockholm, if the train continues south it will probably still apply).
If you're not sure, you might as well put in a refund request, they can only say no.

For cancellations SJ often gives you a "refund or rebook" offer. Enter your ticket details and see if there is one. If so just click the refund-button. https://www.sj.se/en/your-journeys/search/
